# plot() broken in every single usage

Tags: r, graphics

First, the error:

```
Error in (function (file = if (onefile) "Rplots.pdf" else "Rplot%03d.pdf",  : 
  cannot open file 'Rplots.pdf'
```

This error occurs on *any* invocation of plot(), including plot(1).

It had functioned correctly for a while, but then it stopped and began to throw this error.

I am running this on R Studio - Server Version 1.0.136 with R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21).  All packages have been updated to the latest version.

What broke? I tried reinstalling 'graphics' but it wouldn't let me. Do I have to reinstall R?

As requested, the code that produces this error:

```
plot(1)
```

This error persists across restarting R, restarting R studio, rebooting the server, reinstalling base r, and an unplanned power outage.

Comment: In case you are calling `pdf()` function (or `png`, `jpg`...), you probably forgot to close the file using `dev.off()`.

Comment: I am not calling any pdf.  As I said, this error occurs even when you use plot(1)

Comment: Try calling dev.off() anyway. Call it repeatedly until you get an error message that the NULL device can't be closed. Or restart R and make sure that no previous workspace is loaded.

Comment: That was the message that it gave when it ran. "Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)"

Comment: Try restarting R. If this comes up again, please share enough of the script so that we can make at least an informed guess.

Comment: I have restarted R. The command that causes the error is plot(1).  This is in a new script, with a new r session, in R studio.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried multiple things to resolve this and eventually the nuclear option worked.

The problem was the output device was assigned to `plot()` somehow. `getOption("device")` should output the definition of the function `plot()`.  If you have this issue, reassigning the graphics output to RStudio will not fix it, and calling to `dev.off()` won't either.

This was resolved with a reinstall of R Studio Server and base-r.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Resaving the code with a new filename resolves the problem, however, you will have to rename it for each subsequent run.

Hopefully someone has a better answer out there.